# CMake library dependencies and build order

Tags: cmake

Here is the problem.
I have two libraries (A and B) and one executable - C, which uses both.
I can describe the project in two ways

### method 1:

add_library(A ...)

add_library(B ...)
target_link_libraries(B A)

add_executable(C ...)
target_link_libraries(C B)

### method 2:

add_library(A ...)

add_library(B ...)

add_executable(C ...)
target_link_libraries(C A B)

In the first case, when in Visual Studio I build project C, it builds them sequentially: A, then B, then C.
In the second case, Visual Studio builds A and B at the same time in parallel, then builds C.

Sure, I like the second way - the build is faster.
Sure, I want to use the first way - because I do not have to list all library dependencies in project C.

That is, I want CMake to understand that when linking C, it should add library A even though I did not specify it in target_link_libraries(C B) command. And, I want Visual Studio to build A and B in parallel because they are static libraries and there is no need to build them sequentially.

Is it at all possible?

Comment: If you include `PUBLIC` in `target_link_libraries`, that should propagate the dependencies also to the next target. Would that work for your situation?

Comment: I have no problem with propagating dependencies. I have problem with build parallelism. I do not understand your answer.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example where your build fails in parallel but succeeds in serial?

Comment: My builds do not fail. I have already explained, but I can repeat.
"In the first case, when in Visual Studio I build project C, it builds them sequentially: A, then B, then C. In the second case, Visual Studio builds A and B at the same time in parallel, then builds C."
What I want is to describe the project using "method 1", but build them as thought it was described using "method 2". That is, instruct Visual Studio to build libraries A and B in parallel.

Comment: Okay, I see. In that case, with the first method I don't think it's possible. If A is a dependency of B, then B has to wait until A finishes no matter what. What you could do is declare an INTERFACE library D which links to A and B and then link C to D. It's an extra layer of abstraction but then A and B are built in parallel and C only sees one target.